# Auto detect Speech Recognition language

Tags: android, azure, speech-recognition

I am developing an android app which needs Speech recognition functionality, I need app should work same as Google Translator app in which it Google translate auto detect language spoken. I checked with Microsoft Azure Speech recognition and Google Speech recognition API in both the API we need to provide language code. I searched all over but did not get any workaround or solution to achieve similar functionality. Please help.

Comment: got any solutions ?

Comment: Did not get any solution yet.

Comment: Did you manage to get solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I am answering late but it may help

I think problem is very large than it seems. As far as I understood you want to achieve speech-to-text and then translate text to required language.

I think using paid services of microsoft or google or amazon would be helful.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/

https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed my design of the app. Google might provide API in future for achieving this. Thanks for help.